# Image upload quality is awful?

Tags: 7

I've tried nearly everything to get my image quality to improve upon upload. I have an imagestyle on my image upload field that is set to resize uploaded images to 300x300. I've installed ImageMagick (hearing a myth that doing so improves the image quality drastically), but I see no change.

I'm desperate - any idea as to how I can get my images to maintain their quality when uploaded? This seems like it should be a simple thing?

See example below. The image on the left is what it looks like when I resize outside of Drupal (e.g. with Photoshop; see how sharp it is?!) - the image on the right is when it's resized via Drupal image field/image style.

[image]

Comment: Please define "Quality"?

Comment: As in, I have a really sharp 2000 x 2000px image on my desktop. When I upload it via Drupal's image upload field and size it down to 300x300 with image cache, the image is extremely blurry/fuzzy (if I do this same resize in photoshop, the image doesn't get blurry/fuzzy at all). How can I keep this from happening? I want to size it down because my images have a zoom feature that also allows users to view the larger image. @Zachary

Comment: Is there any chance you could upload an example of what's happening?

Comment: @Zachary See image uploaded above :)

Comment: @GiorgosK The correct answer in that link is incorrect - even though it's checked, the answer does not work (I've tried it, and it's even mentioned in the comments).

Comment: There is a 2nd answer did you try it ?

Comment: As far as drupal goes that’s the only obvious answer @Brittany, there aren’t any other configuration options related to jpg quality. This might be something you have to fix in the config of your image library

Comment: @Brittany did you set it to 100%?

Comment: Yes I did @NoSssweat - still no dice :(